# Why am I getting this error in python when i enter into next line of if-else condition?

Tags: python-3.7

```
if cake == "delicious":
    return "yes"
```

> SyntaxError: 'return' outside function

Why I get like this?

Comment: Read https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html?highlight=return#grammar-token-return-stmt: _return may only occur syntactically nested in a function definition_

Comment: What is it that you don't understand in "'return' outside function" ? That's pretty clear: you have a return statement outside a function, which doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can create some functions like this.

```
text  ="delicious" 
def check(text):
    if text=="delicious":
        return 'yes'

check(text)
```

Answer (score -1):

`return` is a keyword which can only appear in a function definition (as the syntax error says). You can simply print your output in an if/else block

```
if cake == 'delicious': print('yes')
```

Comment: @downvoter: Why the downvote? Please consider writing in the comment, why you have downvoted, as SO recommends.